# What is the practical reason in defining a convolution by different indeces

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, generating-functions, convolution

I am taking some time to carefully construct my understanding of generating functions as they are extremely interesting to me in terms of properties and uses.

I am making my way to convolutions now and the formula goes:

For sequences a = {$a_i:i\ge0$} and b = {$b_i:i\ge0$} we have that their convolution $c$ is $$c_n = a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+…+a_nb_0$$ $$=\sum_{i=0}^na_ib_{n-i}$$

My question is why we choose to define the convolution by pairing the $(i)th$ moment of $a$ with the $(n-i)th$ moment of $b$ as opposed to equating the indices for both. What information is being captured by having the sequences run in opposite directions? I tend to come at this from relating the information to probability theory but any approach is welcome.

Comment: I should add, one thing Ive thought of is that, if $a_i$ and $b_i$ are probabilities of individual die rolls, then it would be the case that the convolution would give coefficients/probabilities of rolling a sum of 7 but I don’t know what general property this is alluding to

Comment: This is the "right" thin to consider because it is simultaneously combinatorially meaningful ($c_n$ is the number of ways to build an object by using an $a$-construction and a $b$-construction so that the total size is $n$) and algebraically meaningful (it is what you get when you multiply two generating functions).

Comment: Ah! Thank you- the combinatorial reference is perfect! Would the “shift” to probability then be that, these constructions have certain chances of occurring and their sum represents the total chance of constructing object size n (from b and a)?

Comment: Outside  of probabilities the meaning of the convolution $a\ast b$ is *make shifts of $b$ by every integer and take the weighted sum of all the shifted versions, using $a$ for the weighting*. We prefer $a \ast b(n) = \sum_i a(i) b(n-i)$ versus $ \sum_i a(i) b(n+i)$ mainly because it gives $a \ast b=b\ast a$. You can also argue that $n\mapsto b(n-1)$ is $b$ shifted by $1$ to the right, so it makes sense to use $a(1)$ when weighting it. It also gives that the convolution of two causal sequences is causal.

Comment: I do not have any insight into the use of convolutions or generating functions in probability, sorry!

Comment: I don't know whether that helps, but there is a beautiful video of 3b1b taking a deep dive on exactly this question. You can find it (here)[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuXjwB4LzSA].

Comment: This video was amazing, thanks for sharing it!